# Cannot press App_Data in Add ASP.NET Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with the MVC project in VS.

I have noticed the old topics about this problem but have not gotten any good answers..
What should I do? Some are discussing creating a new folder, App_Code but some say that I should absolutely not do that? (And I haven't figurered out how to that either so...)

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: App_Data or App_Code? Your title and content are different

Comment: Yes @codingbiz because they are different things. The App_Data is a "button" and people have written in old topics that you should create a folder called App_Code.

Comment: I have now found the answer, by @rulestein,
" I came across this problem too. You have to make sure the project is selected in the Solution Explorer and not just some file or folder within the project. If the project is selected, your Add ASP.NET folder options will become enabled. Alternatively, right click on the project in the tree and go to Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder. That will make sure the project is indeed selected."

Thank you!!